# jQuery - Need help stopping animation on click command

Tags: jquery, function, click, jquery-animate

With a few of your help I was able to get the jquery I wanted to work flawlessly, except for one thing.. the animation doesn't stop when i click on the buttons.

**Scenario:**
I have an Image, and 3 buttons underneath labeled "1","2", and "3". The jquery will automate the click function every 4500ms and switch from 1 to 2, then 2 to 3 and continuously loop. However the problem is, if I manually click on a 1,2,3 button the animation does not stop.

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

**jQuery:**

```
var tabs;
var len;
var index = 1;
var robot;

function automate() {
    tabs.eq((index%len)).trigger('click');
    index++;
}

robot = setInterval(automate, 5500);

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".imgs").hide();
 jQuery(".img_selection a").click(function(){
        stringref = this.href.split('#')[1];
        $(".img_selection a[id$=_on]").removeAttr('id');
        this.id = this.className + "_on";
        jQuery('.imgs').hide();
        if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0,3) == "6.0") {
            jQuery('.imgs#' + stringref).show();
        } else
            jQuery('.imgs#' + stringref).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
    $('.img_selection a').removeAttr('id').eq(0).trigger('click');
    tabs = jQuery(".img_selection a");
    len = tabs.size();
});
```

I tried adding the below code, with a lot of help from this website, but to no avail..

**CODE:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".imgs").hide().click(function(){
  clearInterval(robot);
 });
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- TOP IMAGE ROTATION -->
    <div id="upper_image">
        <div id="img1" class="imgs">
         <p><img src="images/top_image.jpg" width="900" height="250" alt="" border="0" /></p>
        </div>
         <div id="img2" class="imgs">
         <p><img src="images/top_image2.jpg" width="900" height="250" alt="" border="0" /></p>
        </div>
        <div id="img3" class="imgs">
         <p><img src="images/top_image3.jpg" width="900" height="250" alt="" border="0" /></p>
        </div>
        </div>
<!-- / TOP IMAGE ROTATION -->
<!-- TOP IMAGE SELECTION -->
     <ul class="img_selection">
            <li><a id="img1_on" class="img1" href="#img1">1</a></li>
            <li><a class="img2" href="#img2">2</a></li>
            <li><a class="img3" href="#img3">3</a></li>
        </ul>

<!-- / TOP IMAGE SELECTION -->
```

Comment: Just for my own clarification, when you click on something with a class of imgs, have you made sure your click function is getting called?

Comment: No, is there an easy way to test this so I can see if that function is being called?

Comment: Add alert('here'); to the top of the function.

Comment: This is getting called on pageload, because the automate function is running click, so it's running this and killing the robot. I guess I need to create 2 functions, one labeled click, then one labeled something else, so the automate can run the function labeled something else, while in the click function I can manually select and then that will contain the clearinterval(robot);

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML I can't be certian but it looks like you are adding the click event to the image and not the button.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery(".img_selection a").click(function(){ 
        clearInterval(robot); 
    });
```

If that doesn't work you could always create a local variable to pause the animation.

```
var pause = false;

jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
    jQuery(".imgs").hide().click(function(){    
        pause = true;   
    }); 

function automate() {  
    if (pause) return;
    tabs.eq((index%len)).trigger('click');     
    index++;     
}
```

Comment: I think my problem is the automate trigger is click, so if I add ClearInterval(robot); in a click(function) it's going to kill the process.

I tried your 2nd piece of code as well, but that stopped the entire process as well.. I believe because the trigger runs click, then automatically sets pause=true, regardless.

Hrmm..

Comment: If you can add the HTML it will be a lot clearer what the issue is.

Comment: The click event in the first code block should work. Can you verify if you've tried it.

Comment: It works, but it's ran on pageload due to the automate function, so it runs clearinterval(robot); before you manually click on the button. So therefore the slideshow doesn't work anymore